# How can I solve the Inkscape SyntaxError when trying to save a gcode?

Tags: inkscape, cnc, pythonplotter

I've been struggling for the past few days to install and uninstall different versions of **Inkscape** in hope that one of them will finally convert my image into gcode. Unfortunately, nothing seems to work. (I also have installed version Python 3.8)

As a backstory, I'm working on a CNC machine, specifically a pen plotter and while I was following a tutorial for it, I got stuck in quite some things. The one I'm addressing now it's the Inkscape SyntaxError that I'm getting after using the *MI GRBL Z-AXIS Servo Controller* from the menu.

```
Inkscape has received additional data from the script executed.  The script did not return an error, but this may indicate the results will not be as expected. 
File "servo.py", line 52
    def bezierslopeatt(((bx0,by0),(bx1,by1),(bx2,by2),(bx3,by3)),t):
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In the tutorial, it says that after installing Inkscape, I have to download the MI Inkscape Extention zip and copy and paste those files to the C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\extensions path. I've been doing that, I've also tried without changing the files, I've tried with older versions, such as Inkscape 0.92, 0.92.5, and even the latest one Inkscape 1.0.2 and also different versions of the MI Extension (from 2017, 2022).
The error persists and it won't let me save any gcode file.

Hope someone can tell me if I'm doing something wrong or if I should be doing something else. Or if anyone knows a good replacement for Inkscape if this problem can't be solved. Thank you in advance.^^

Comment: Hi! There are similar reports [here](https://inkscape.org/forums/cutplot/problem-with-mi-grbl-extension/), [here](https://inkscape.org/forums/beyond/gcode-extension-sytax-error/), and [here](https://github.com/mbastl/bastl-laser-tool/issues/3). It seems this is a conflict with Python versions, and there are suggested solutions posted.

Comment: Hey Juancho, thank you. I already read those posts and tried the suggested solutions but nothing worked. However, I think I found a solution by saving the drawing from Inkscape to an svg file and then using a gcode online converter.

Comment: The latest version of Inkscape is not `1.0.2`. At the time of writing, the latest version is `1.1.2` and the `1.2` release is expected in a week.

Comment: @s.ouchene I see, I think I have mistaken the digit, oops.